# Laravel presenters for JSON responses

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I’ve recently discovered that presenters ([like this one](https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/laravel-auto-presenter)) implement the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and are a great way to add fields and logic to existing Laravel models. Take the following example for my question below:

```
// Tack on a new readable timestamp field.
public function timeago()
{
    return $this->object->created_at->whenForHumans();
}

// Wrap an existing field with some formatting logic
public function created_at()
{
    return $this->object->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

I can then use these presenter fields in my view:

```
{{ $object->timeago }}
{{ $object->created_at }}
```

**How would you implement the decorator pattern for an API that returns JSON responses rather than Blade views?** In all the Laravel/JSON articles I have read, objects are immediately returned without undergoing any transformation / presenter logic. e.g.:

```
// converting a model to JSON
return User::find($id)->toJson();

// returning a model directly will be converted to JSON
return User::all();

// return associated models
return User::find($id)->load('comments')->get();
```

How can I implement presenter fields in my JSON response?

```
$object->timeago
$object->created_at
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, User::all returns JSON, so do something like:

Some function to get data and return a decorated response:

```
public function index()
{
    $news = News::all();

    return $this->respond([
            'data' => $this->newsTransformer->transformCollection($news->toArray())
        ]
    );
}
```

The above function will call Transformer::transformCollection:

```
<?php namespace Blah\Transformers;

abstract class Transformer {

    public function transformCollection(array $items)
    {
        return array_map([$this, 'transform'], $items);
    }

    public abstract function transform($item);
}
```

which in turn will call NewsTransformer::transform():

```
public function transform($news)
{
    return [
        'title' => $news['title'],
        'body'  =>  $news['body'],
        'active' => (boolean) $news['some_bool'],
        'timeago' => // Human readable
        'created_at' => // Y-m-d
    ];
}
```

The end result being JSON with the format you require, in this case:

```
{
    data: {
        title: "Some title",
        body: "Some body...",
        active: true,
        timeago: "On Saturday, 1st of March",
        created_at: "2014-03-01"
    }
}
```

By the way, [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) has an excellent series on building APIs -- hope that helps!

For clarity, the respond function in the first code snippet just wraps the data with a status code, and any headers, something like:

```
    return Response::json($data, 200);
```

Comment: You can override `toJson` in your models instead of returning custom responses. It's a lot more cleaner.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv, I've found that you must override the [`toArray` function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2359) because Laravel doesn't call the toJson method when returning a collection. However both methods (Model::toJson and Collection::toJson) do call toArray for each model.